# Refreshing OSGI Bundle context, Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler

Tags: spring, mongodb, osgi, applicationcontext

I need to refresh my application context during runtime. In order to do that, I'm executing following steps: 
1. Create new appliction-context.xml outside my OSGI bundle 
2. Copy old app ctx into new one, using 
`InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/spring/application-context.xml"));` 
3. Refreshing app ctx, which means, switching to new one, created outside bundle
`ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(newCtxPath);
((ConfigurableApplicationContext)ctx).refresh();`

But I'm getting

> Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace
>   [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo]

```
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
```

is inside my application-context.xml, I don't think thats an issue because during compile, everything works fine, problem occurs when I try to refresh ctx during runtime.

edit#
Ofcourse, copying old ctx file to new one is successfull, both files looks exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

I found much simpler solution.

```
public class CtxRefresher implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext context;

    public void refreshApplicationCtx(){
        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)context).refresh();        
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
        context = ctx;      
    }
}
```